# Executing Python from NodeJS (hosted on an external domain)

Tags: python, node.js, express

So I have the following node.js express server running:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const PythonShell = require('python-shell');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Please append a search');
});

app.get('/:card', (req, res) => {
    card = [req.params.card]

    var pyshell = new PythonShell('search_card.py', {args: card});

    pyshell.on('message', (message) => {
        res.send(message);
    });

    pyshell.end((err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});

app.listen(9000, () => console.log('App listening on port 9000!'));
```

When I use the app using the local IP of the server (which is hosted within the intranet), everything works fine.

But if I use the external IP, the root of the app works ( / ) so clearly the connection is possible and the port is open, etc, but if I use the search function ( /search_query ), it takes a few seconds (as if the python script is actually running) and then chrome says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (This site can't be reached).

Can anyone explain this behavior?

EDIT:
I put a console.log inside the pyshell.on('message') and the data is being received from the python program. Its as soon as it writes ends that it fails

Comment: does your node logs outputs anything when the error occurs?

Comment: @rafaismyname Unfortunately not

Comment: in both cases they are hosted in the very same machine/process? the only thing different would be that running localhost:3000/search_query works but YOUREXTERNALIP:3000/search_query wont work?

Comment: @rafaismyname Yes, exactly

Comment: are you (and/or the machine trying to execute remotely) under any kind of proxy/firewall? the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and the explanation you gave clearly indicates some kind of network problem...

Comment: @rafaismyname Not that I'm aware of. The remote machine is a raspberry pi hosting the node app, and I'm on a Windows machine. Both devices are in my house on my local network. Edit: From a quick google search, the Pi doesn't come with a firewall installed. So its not a firewall on that side.

Comment: also, would probably worth trying to set express's host address to `0.0.0.0` instead of the default `127.0.0.0` like this: `app.listen(9000, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log('App listening on port 9000!'));`

Comment: if that doesn't work, maybe this thread might help you out: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=128838

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Unfortunately that didn't change anything. I will check that thread out now

Comment: Oh I should also clarify. I'm not connecting to the pi using localhost or 0.0.0.0, I'm using its internal IP (10.0.0.22:9000). That works perfectly. But using my external IP fails

Comment: sorry, no more clues! hope that you find the solution within that thread! :)